# How to make keys for my console.log data and append it to html (Console log result to textboxes)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making matching system (Player vs Player) my target is. How can I make sure that the keys are then appended to my div?

I have already made a key with append before. Here's the snippet

```js
const source = [{
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: 'player1',
    weight: 1900,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: 'player2',
    weight: 1900,
   
  },
  {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: 'player3',
    weight: 1910,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: 'player4',
    weight: 1910,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 5,
    entryName: 'player5',
    weight: 1915,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 6,
    entryName: 'player6',
    weight: 1915,
   
  },
  { 
    entryID: 7,
    entryName: 'player7',
    weight: 1920,
  
  },
  { 
    entryID: 8,
    entryName: 'player8',
    weight: 1920,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 9,
    entryName: 'player9',
    weight: 1930,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 10,
    entryName: 'player10',
    weight: 1930,

  },



  ]


  const combine = (source) => {
    return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr.weight]) {
        const levelArr = acc[curr.weight];
        const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
        if (last.length === 2) {
          levelArr.push([curr])
        } else {
          last.push(curr)
        }
      } else {
        acc[curr.weight] = [
          [curr]
        ];
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})
  };


  var result = combine(source)
  var html = ""
  var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there are more than one keys i.e : 2..

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {

    val.forEach(function(value, index) {

     
        var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
        var handlers = index == 0 ? "handlerM[]" : "handlerW[]"
        var weights = index == 0 ? "weightM[]" : "weightW[]"
        html += `<input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${value.entryID}"> 
                 <input type="text" name="${handlers}" value="${value.entryName}">
                 <input type="text" name="${weights}" value="${value.weight}">
                 `
    })
    })
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

These are my data after doing the function newCombine... Now my target is how can i make keys and append these result as textbox?

[image]

The snippet I provided works when 2 data with the same weight. They are combined in 1 array. Going to my target, Now, I'm having a hard time applying that in my current function which works when 2 data with less than or greater than equal 15 weight difference. Please, help me. Thank you very much.

**html**

```
<div id="appendhere"> </div>
```

**ajax**

```
  function newCombine(data, difference) {
  let nonMatched = [...data]
  const groups = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < nonMatched.length - 1; i++) {
    const first = nonMatched[i]

    inner: for (let j = nonMatched.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      const second = nonMatched[j]
      const delta = Math.abs(first.weight - second.weight)

      if (delta <= difference && first.entryName !== second.entryName) {
        const groupKey = `${first.weight}_${second.weight}`
        groups[groupKey] = [first, second]
        nonMatched = nonMatched.filter(
          obj => obj.entryID != first.entryID && obj.entryID != second.entryID
        )
        i = -1
        break inner
      }
    }
  }
  return { ...groups, ...nonMatched }
}    



$(document).ready(function() {


var entry_list =$('#entry_list1').DataTable({ 
      
 
        "ajax": {
              "url": "<?php echo site_url('report/controlget')?>",
            "type": "get",
            
           success: function(data) {
                
            const source = data;
             const a = newCombine(source, 15);
            
            console.log(a);
            
            
        //How can i append my key here?
            
            
            },
            }
    
 
    });
    
 });
```

Comment: Why can't you just do what you did in the first example in the second?(going through the objects and appending the values to result.innerHTML) What happens when you try this?

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

I will avoid console and div-related stuff here to make sure that the solution is reusable in any manner. You can do with the result whatever you want, including adding it to a div or displaying it on the console.

## Problem statement

We need to group items using the criteria, according to which weight difference is smaller than a given value, eg. 15.

## Perfection is unachievable

Let's consider the example when we have weights such as 1900, 1910 and 1920. We cannot have a weight group of (1900, 1910 and 1920) because 1920 - 1900 = 20 > 15.

We could have weight groups of the like of (1900, 1910), (1920) or (1900), (1910, 1920)

## An imperfect, but probably good-enough solution

```js
const source = [{
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: 'player1',
    weight: 1900,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: 'player2',
    weight: 1900,
   
  },
  {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: 'player3',
    weight: 1910,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: 'player4',
    weight: 1910,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 5,
    entryName: 'player5',
    weight: 1915,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 6,
    entryName: 'player6',
    weight: 1915,
   
  },
  { 
    entryID: 7,
    entryName: 'player7',
    weight: 1920,
  
  },
  { 
    entryID: 8,
    entryName: 'player8',
    weight: 1920,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 9,
    entryName: 'player9',
    weight: 1930,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 10,
    entryName: 'player10',
    weight: 1930,

  },
];

let groups = [];

for (let item of source) {
    let found = false;
    for (let group of groups) {
        if (!found) {
            let isFit = true;
            for (let element of group) {
                if (Math.abs(element.weight - item.weight) > 15) isFit = false;
            }
            if (isFit) {
                group.push(item);
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!found) groups.push([item]);
}

document.getElementById("foo").innerText = JSON.stringify(groups);
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

We loop the elements and iterate each one into the first group that would match. If none of the groups are matching, we create a new group.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for answering. I kinda find it difficult analyze and I'm sorry for that. My target is if player 1 has 1900 weight and player 2 has 1915 weight. They'll be match and will be in the same array because my requirement is less than or greater than equal to 15.  Please, see the screenshot above for reference. Thank you. Seeing the result of your answer is confusing for me. I'm sorry for the lack of knowledge. Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer I would be happy to help, but I'm not sure what "less than or greater than equal to 15" means. My assumption was that you wanted to group all records into groups of 1 or more elements where each element has a distance smaller than or equal than 15 in comparison to any other element. As a result, your sample input is grouped into 2 groups, the first group having a range between 1900 and 1915 and the second group having a range between 1920 and 1930. If this is incorrect, then you have a different aim than the one I understood. In that case you need to clarify the aim.